# ASyncTask крэшит приложение

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Здравстуйте! В главной активности в onCreate стартует AsyncTask, который должен загружать xml-страницу и возвращать ее как строчку. Судя по логам, он загружает xml и сразу же вылетает. Помогите разобраться.

Код для Таска:

```
class AsyncLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
StringBuilder builder;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        Log.i("TAG", "open connection");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            builder.append(reader.readLine());
            Log.i("TAG", reader.readLine());
        }
        if (reader.readLine() == null) {
            Log.i("TAG", "NULL");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}}
```

код главной активности

```
 AsyncLoader mAsyncLoader = new AsyncLoader();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAsyncLoader.execute();}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в цикле написать так: while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            Log.i("TAG", line);
        } Вы ведь читаете строку, проверяя её на null, и сразу её забываете. И тут же читаете следующие строки, а их может и не быть.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!